# Can I add color to column with colorbox or some other method that LaTex native?

Tags: tables, color

Can I add color to column with colorbox or some other method that LaTex native?

What I want to display is below:

[image]

have tried

```
\begin{vmatrix}
\quad 5 \qquad 1 \qquad \colorbox{grey}{1} \quad\\
\quad -6 \qquad 2 \qquad \colorbox{grey}{0} \quad\\
\quad -5 \qquad -5 \qquad \colorbox{grey}{0} \quad\\
\end{vmatrix}
```

and

```
\begin{vmatrix}
\quad 5 \qquad 1 \qquad \bbox[grey, 20px]{1} \quad\\
\quad -6 \qquad 2 \qquad \bbox[grey, 20px]{0} \quad\\
\quad -5 \qquad -5 \qquad \bbox[grey, 20px]{0} \quad\\
\end{vmatrix}
```

Comment: Could you please add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you have tried so far?

Comment: You might be interested in using the `\columncolor` command from the `colortbl` package.